# How do I click a button using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to crawl review data on an app from a Google Play website page using Python and Selenium. What I'm trying to do here is to click the "Full Review" button to see the entire text of each review.

But I keep running into these errors each time:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

or

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

or

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc  "}
```

The element for the button is this:

```
<button class="LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc  " jsaction="click:TiglPc" jsname="gxjVle">Full Review</button>
```

The xpath for the button is this:

```
//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[26]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div/button
```

And this is the code I'm using for xpath:

```
full_review = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[26]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/div/button')
full_review.click()
```

I can't find the button by class name, xpath or anything.
Could anyone help me figure out this problem? In addition, is it possible to find the element by jsname? 
I would really appreciate if you could help.

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to just just the class?  driver.find_element_by_class_name('LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc').click()

Comment: Why not find any `button` whose text is "Full Review" and skip the class / id bits? Note that if there are more than one such button, you probably need to call click on the elements of the list of buttons...

Comment: I've tried it and kept getting this error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc"}

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using xpath whenever possible, it's the most brittle selector.

id > CSS > Xpath

For your button, this css selector should work:

`button[jsname='gxjVle']`

You'll probably need to specify the child as that probably won't be unique

Comment: I just tried ID and it didn't work. How do you put that into the parentheses after css_selector? full_review=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(button[jsname='gxjVle']).click()?
this shows syntax error

Comment: it'll take in a string, so:
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[jsname='gxjVle']").click()

Comment: This works for me, just quickly implemented it for a random app in the store: driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[jsname='gxjVle']:first-of-type")).click()

import org.openqa.selenium.By

Comment: it says there's no module like org.openqa.selenium.By

Comment: Just do it in whichever way you're used to in finding elements via css selector. Is it this? But it just needs to be a String. i.e. driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("button[jsname='gxjVle']:first-of-type").click()

Answer (score 0):

1. Your XPath selector is a little bit flaky, you can simplify it to be something like:

   ```
   //button[text()='Full Review']
   ```
2. You're using the wrong function, if you're looking for a single unique element you should be using [`WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) one, mind that `element`, not `elements`
3. It's better to use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) just in case element is not immediately available in DOM (for example if you're [testing application built using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/))

Assuming all above:

```
full_review = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Full Review']")))
```

Comment: I tried this: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
full_review = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Full Review']"))).
this shows error "name WebDriverWait is not defined"

Comment: Yeah thanks for the advice.. By the way, it still shows the same error, webdriverwait not defined.